# MySql: does max_user_connection concern SUPER user?

Tags: mysql

On MySql 5.7 I've setup variable `max_user_connection = 35`.

I have several users, their number of simultaneous connections is effectively limited.

Now I have created a brand new user with `SUPER` privilege. Is this user's connection is concerned by the `max_user_connection` variable too ?

Thanks

Edit: I know the [max_user_connection](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_user_connections) documentation, but this specific point is not covered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it the limit counts for every connection independent of which kind of user connects

> This limits the number of simultaneous connections that can be made by any given account

See [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-resources.html)

Comment: I agree, and your answer is the one. I just made a test, I limited the ```max_user_connection``` to 2, then using multiple terminals connects to my database : I received a "User root already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections" ... Thanks

Comment: Every network connection starts with a HELLO package and when it refuses because of max connections it doesn't know which user connects